# Posting an answer triggers the "Confirm that you want to leave" dialogue

Tags: bug, answers, user-interface

For the past few days (since the new profile pages came out, I think), each time I try to post an answer on U&L, I get this dialog when I click on "Post your answer":

[image: confirm that you want to leave popup]

If I choose "Stay on page" and try to submit my answer again, I get the new answers notification banner:

[image: new answers notification banner]

And attempting to submit again, I am told my answer is a dupe since, apparently, it was actually submitted on my first attempt:

[image: Duplicate answer notification]

As I just found out when posting this question, I get the same issue when posting questions (at least on meta) as well. Choosing to "Leave page" submits the question (and, presumably the answer) as expected but this is very annoying.

Clearing my browser's cache lets me post one answer normally but the next time I try to post, I get the same issue again.

This is on Firefox 37.0 on a 64bit Debian (LMDE). What gives?

Comment: What extensions are you using? Also does the requisite clearing of your browser's cache have any effect on this?

Comment: @slm I think that clearing the cache fixed it. I should have thought of that, thanks.

Comment: @slm I take that back, it's back again. Apparently, clearing the cache stops it but something is loaded into the cache again.